# Align image to the bottom of each screen Corona SDK

Tags: ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk

I have a image that I want to atomically bring down and scale depending on the screen size (iPhone 4/5/6/plus).

I can't use align because it only works with text view.
Is there any other way

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help: [Resolution Independence: Adaptive Content Scaling in Corona](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/28/resolution-independence-adaptive-content-scaling-in-corona/)

Comment: The link you have provided looks like dead. Please check the source.